# Add "Tags" to wp.newPost Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i made a php script that post a new article on a wordpress site.

This is a part of my code:

```
$terms_names = array('post_tag' => $tags);

$content = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status'=>'pending',
'post_title'=> 'TEST',
'post_author'=> 1,
'post_excerpt' => 'SOMETEXT',
'post_content'=> 'POSTBODY',
'post_date_gmt' => '',
'comment_status'=>1
'ping_status'=>0,
'post_thumbnail' => $results,
'terms_names' => $terms_names

);
$params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,false);
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.newPost',$params);
```

there's the possibility to add a post tags?
Thanks to all

Regards

**EDIT:**

Problem Solved :)
I've added the `$terms_name` array,
I've just edited my code :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just add tags to your array (Edit: as array or without <>)

```
$tags = array('tag1', 'tag2');
$content = array(
'post_type'     => 'post',
'post_status'   =>'pending',
'post_title'    => 'TEST',
'post_author'   => 1,
'post_excerpt'  => 'SOMETEXT',
'post_content'  => 'POSTBODY',
'post_date_gmt' => '',
'comment_status'=> 1
'ping_status'   => 0,
'post_thumbnail'=> $results,
'tags_input'    => $tags
);
```

wp.newPost accepts all fileds supported by wp_insert_post

Comment: How can i use this with curl?
Beacuse i put the $request in Curl

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);`

Comment: Yes, all other information works well, the post is created successfull, but the tag doesn't appears

Comment: for sure it works with tags from dbase, I will made a test and update my answer

Comment: Finally Found A Solution :D
I edit my first post with my solution

Comment: Thanks Michal, i've really appreciated your Help :)